# Removing property page from Layer Property Sheet using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I need to remove definition query tab of the Feature Layer or Table property page. Is it possible to do this with arcobjects at all?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```cs
UID uid_comCategory = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID();
//Component Category of Esri Layer Property Pages
uid_comCategory.Value = "{1476C782-6F57-11D2-A2C6-080009B6F22B}";

UID uid = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID();
// GUID of esriCartoUI.LayerDefinitionQueryPropertyPage
uid.Value = "{1476C788-6F57-11D2-A2C6-080009B6F22B}"; 

var ccm = new ComponentCategoryManager();
ccm.SetupObject("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ArcGIS\\Desktop10.2\\bin\\FeatureLayerUI.dll", uid, uid_comCategory, false);
```

I get this error at the last line:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

Furthurmore I tried to remove it manually using Component Category Manager utility, but it doesn't work there, too.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious why would you ever want to remove the ability to set a definition query? That's an incredibly useful and important property of a FeatureLayer.

Comment: @Hornbydd, I am trying to restrict users from viewing all data within a Layer or Table. In other word I want to secure data using a definition query. Therefore, Users must not be able to clear the definition query. This is part of a system design that is modeled with an ArcMap extension!